# Using Monotouch how do i implement a UITabBarController as my RootViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm totally new to iOS programming using Monotouch...  I'm using this code to create my navigation root view.

```
window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

UINavigationController rootNavController = new UINavigationController ();
window.RootViewController = rootNavController;

UIViewController tabView = new TabContainer ();
rootNavController.PushViewController (tabView, false);
```

My TabContainer class inherits the UITabBarController class and I have several UIViewControllers being added to the UITabBarController class.

```
var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
     tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5
};

base.ViewControllers = tabs;
```

After clicking on one of the tabs, my ViewController will load with a UITableView inside it and i can still see the TabBarController at the bottom.  If i now click on any of the table cells i am pushing a new view and the TabBarController is hidden.

```
tblSource.OnRowSelected += (object sender, TableSourceStationGroup.RowSelectedEventArgs e) => {
            e.tableView.DeselectRow (e.indexPath, true);
            stationView = new viewStation (itemList[e.indexPath.Row].Name, itemList[e.indexPath.Row].Id, itemList[e.indexPath.Row].Stations);
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(stationView, true);
```

How can i keep the TabBarController from hiding when I push a new view?  I think i am missing something fundamental here about the structure of my application.

Answer (score 4):

You want to setup your hierarchy like this:

```
                           Tab1 -> Nav1 -> View
Root --> Tab Controller -> Tab2 -> Nav2 -> View
                           Tab3 -> Nav3 -> View
```

So each tab will have it's own Nav controller, which will have an initial view pushed onto it.

In your example you have your Nav controller as the root, containing the Tab controller.  This is backwards - you want the Tab controller to contain the Nav controllers.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please take the time to mark this as the "correct" answer - there should be a checkmark button (or something) like that you can click next to it.